# How can I add `IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool` to a group?

Tags: c#, windows

I am adding a user to a group using:

```
// reference System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine))
using (var group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, GroupName))
using (var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, Username))
{
    if (group == null || user == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("User '{0}' or group '{1}' does not exist", Username, GroupName));
    }

    if (!group.Members.Contains(user))
    {
        group.Members.Add(user);
        group.Save();
    }
}
```

But `UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity` returns null with `IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool` even though it works with `NT Service\w32time` and `Administrator`.  Using `lusrmgr.msc`, the user can be added without incedent, but I cannot use `UserPrincipal`, `GroupPrincipal`, or `Principal` to get the user.

How can I get a `Principal` for `IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool` or otherwise add it to a local group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can round-trip through a SID to get a `Principal`:

```
private Principal GetUserPrincipal(PrincipalContext context, string name)
{
    var nta = new NTAccount(name);
    try
    {
        var sid = nta.Translate(typeof(SecurityIdentifier)).Value;
        return Principal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.Sid, sid);
    }
    catch (IdentityNotMappedException)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```